# Declaring a 2D array without knowing its size in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to use a 2-D array but I can't know its size in advance. So my question is: how to declare it? And then how to add values into it?

```
String[,] tabConfig = new String[?, 4];
foreach(blabla with i)
{
    tabConfig[i, 0] = a;
    tabConfig[i, 1] = b;
    tabConfig[i, 2] = c;
    tabConfig[i, 3] = d;
}
```

I know I can also use a list but I am not very familiar with it.

Thank you!

EDIT: Brace yourselves! Here come my true code with Jon Skeet's help!

```
List<string[]> tabConfig = new List<string[]>();
String[] temp = new String[4];//The array that will be inside the List
int line = 0, column = 0;

foreach (XmlNode e in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    if (e.Attributes["Server"].Value == choice)
    {
        temp[0] = e.Attributes["Serveur"].Value;//Here is value 'a'

        column = 1;
        foreach (XmlNode i in e.ChildNodes)
        {
            temp[colonne] = i.InnerText;//Here are values 'b', 'c' and 'd'
            column++;
        }
        tabConfig.Add(temp);//Put a new line into the List
        line++;
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
foreach(string[] array in tabConfig)
    foreach(String txt in array)
        Console.WriteLine(txt);
```

Comment: Can't you count whatever you are iterating over in your loop?

Comment: If you need dynamic sizing, use a List of lists instead (or an array of lists of a list of arrays if you know one dimension). `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: So you are saying I could do 
for(blabla i){ count++; } 
String[,] tabConfig = new String[count, 4]; 
and then my foreach(blabla i){} ?
I don't find it really profitable. I am sure there is a more dynamic solution.

Comment: I would like to put in a word for Lists...they are utterly brilliant things...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So my question is: how to declare it?

You can't. All arrays in .NET are fixed size: you can't create an array instance without knowing the size.

It looks to me like you should have a `List<T>` - and I'd actually create a class to hold the four properties, rather than just using four elements of an array, probably. You *could* use a list of arrays:

```
List<string[]> tabConfig = new List<string[]>();
foreach (...)
{
    tabConfig.Add(new string[] { a, b, c, d });
}
```

... but then you need to know what those four elements mean in terms of ordering etc, which is likely to make the rest of your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a

```
List<List<string>>
```

for this, dont' you?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better of using a dictionary something like

```
IDictionary<string, IList<TYPE>> myContainer = new Dictionary<string, List<TYPE>>();
myContainer.Add("key1", new List<TYPE>());
myContainer["key1"].Add("SomeTYPE-1");
myContainer["key1"].Add("SomeTYPE-2");
myContainer["key1"].Add("SomeTYPE-3");

myContainer.Add("key2", new List<TYPE>());
myContainer["key2"].Add("A");
myContainer["key2"].Add("B");
myContainer["key2"].Add("C");
```

**Update**
As commented by @jon you use a dictionary if you are wanting to access elements of your 2d array by some form of key, which may / may not be useful in your situation. If you don't want a key based dictionary then stick with what @jon posted.

Comment: There's no indication that a dictionary is appropriate here. There's no obvious key, and an array preserves order whereas a dictionary doesn't.

Comment: Jon Skeet is right: I need to preserve order. And actually my a,b,c,d variables are already dictionnaries. So it would go dictionary of dictionary of list of array... I am sure C# language can do better than that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can do a foreach, you can know the size of it. If you know the size, you can create the aray with the necessary size.

But I would use a List for it. It's friendlier for that type of situation.

http://www.functionx.com/csharp/builtinclasses/list.htm

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
private struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

List<MyStruct> myList = new List<MyStruct>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
public string one{get;set;}
public string two{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can make a list of this object like

```
List<MyClass> list1=new List<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

if I were you, I'd put as array-size the length of the list you are iterating because array must be declared with a fixed size