# I need help figuring out how to work with c# matrix

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand how to work with matrix in C#.

I used to code in Java:

- `int[][]arr=new int[2][5];` or
- `int [][]arr={{2,3,4,5},{9,3}};`

When I try to create an array in C# I only success to make this way:

```
int[,]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
```

This line works for me but it requires same length in every column. I also try to use `GetLength()` when I worked with for loops and I could get only the number of columns and the size of the second column.

1. Is there any way to create a matrix with any size I want like the java examples?
2. How can I get the size of the rows/columns?

Comment: A `int[,]` isn't equivalent to `int[][]`.

Comment: Seems like this has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521313/declaring-a-2d-array-without-knowing-its-size-in-c-sharp

Comment: Here's the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way to create a matrix with any size I want like the java examples

The term for such matrices is *jagged array*. Unlike `int[,]`, this is an array of arrays; you can create it like this:

```
int [][] arr= { new[] {2,3,4,5}, new[] {9,3} };
```

> 2. How can I get the size of the rows/columns?

Now that this is an array of arrays, you can access `Length` of each item in `arr` the same way that you do in Java:

```
for (var r = 0 ; r != arr.Length ; r++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Row {0} has {1} columns.", r, arr[r].Length);
    for (var c = 0 ; c != arr[r].Length ; c++) {
        ...
    }
}
```